# JSP display list of files/folders with icons

Tags: java, jsp, tags, taglib

I am displaying a number of files on the JSP.

EG:

1. abc.jpg
2. xyz.txt
3. pqr.pdf etc

Now I want the **icon** as well with the files on the JSP.

Is there any library for the same so that i can add and use  or i have to go with the traditional mime type and use if - else and display image by comparing ???

Suggest the best possible way please.

Comment: *"Now I want the **icon** as well with the files"*  What do you mean by 'the' icon?  Each OS would display whatever icon they feel is appropriate for the file, and showing an OS X icon for an image will not look very natural to the Windows user.

Comment: By icon i mean like for pdf files we show red coloured file icon, similarly for txt files white coloured icon with lines is there. so i want icon image with the file name.

Comment: *"similarly for txt files white coloured icon with lines is there."*  I know what you mean, but you apparently don't understand what I am saying.  E.G.  The icon for a text file might be 'mostly white with pale blues lines across it' on both OS X & Windows *but they will still appear to be different to the **end user.***

Comment: ok. I got what u are saying. Then what should i do now ? Should i add my own images in my application and use them or is there any other way ??

Comment: *"Should i add my own images in my application"*  That is probably the approach I would take.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a component which will use "file icons library" to select apropriate icon according file extention.